# Project that I just opened "could not be opened"?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS2012 C++ project.  I can open the project by clicking on the .sln file, but when I open VS2012 and try to open the project from the Start Page, I get this message:

```
"TestApp2" could not be opened.
Do you want to remove the reference(s) to it from the Recent list(s)?
```

I don't get this message for all projects, just this one.

I'm trying to run it from the Start Page because I want to run the code as an Administrator.  I can right-click the VS2012 icon in the Start Menu and click "Run as Administrator", but right-clicking the .sln doesn't provide this option.

Is there something I can do to fix the project so it can be opened from the Start Page?  Or is there another way to open the project as an Administrator?

Comment: you may moved the project TestApp2 to a different location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that is stored in the memory for Visual Studio, is now different. This is the only way that could happen. So, remove it from the pinned recent solutions, open it manually, and then it will have the correct linkage in the Visual Studio menu.

Sorry, didn't see prior post on same solution. :)